# show a function remains positive for a given domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{2}{6x^2}$, show that if $\displaystyle x > \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$, then $f(x) > 0$.

What can I do to show this?

Comment: For any $x\ne0$, $f(x)>0$; since $x^2>0$.

Comment: You can start from the inequality for $ \ x \ $ and "build" toward an inequality related to the function:  $ \ x > \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{1}{x} > \sqrt{3} \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{1}{x^2} > 3 \ $ , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's simplify our function.
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{6x^2}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3x^2}$$
We want $f(x)>0$. We know that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{3x^2}$, so let's substitute $\dfrac{1}{3x^2}$ for $f(x)$.
$$\dfrac{1}{3x^2}>0$$
$$\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x^2}>0$$
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2}>0$$
When $x < 0$, $\dfrac{1}{x^2}>0$. When $x=0$, $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is undefined. When $x > 0$, $\dfrac{1}{x^2} > 0$. S for all the real numbers except $0$, $\dfrac{1}{x^2} > 0$. Our solution is:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\{x \ | \ x \in \mathbb R, \ x \neq 0\}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x>\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$ then $f(x)>\frac{2}{6(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}})^2}=\frac{2}{6*\frac{1}{3}}=1>0$. Done.